# How to remove whitespace from a mkdir()

Tags: php, str-replace, trim

How would I remove the white space from something like, `this is a example` and change that  to `thisisaexample` i am using this with mkdir. I tried the `trim()` and the `str_replace(' ', '', mkdir())` but neither seemed to work.

code to make directories:

```
if (isset($_POST['mkdir']) && !empty($folder_name)) {
    mkdir($directory . $folder_name);
    mkdir($directory . $folder_name . '/uploads/'));
    mkdir($directory . $folder_name . '/uploads/' . $_SESSION['user']);
```

Comment: Why are you passing just `mkdir()`?

Comment: [`mkdir()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`](http://www.php.net/mkdir) - you can't use it in `str_replace()`, you probably want to do it the otehr way around (pass the "fixed string" to `mkdir()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're doing something else wrong. Try:

```
mkdir( str_replace(' ', '', "this is an example") )
```

Comment: Would `"this is an example"` correspond to the directory?

Comment: The above statement will create a directory named `thisisanexample`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace()`:

```
$folder_name = 'this is a example';
$folder_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $folder_name);
if (isset($_POST['mkdir']) && !empty($folder_name)) {
    mkdir($directory . $folder_name);
    mkdir($directory . $folder_name . '/uploads/'));
    mkdir($directory . $folder_name . '/uploads/' . $_SESSION['user']);
}
```

**CAUTION:** If you are using user input for this, this will not be safe. You *must* do more than check for white space in that context.

Comment: I still get spaces. Does the mkdir have to be in a variable?

Comment: @HeyItsProdigy Don't use `mkdir()` as a parameter. Call it and pass `$str` to it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 No, it won't.  OP says he wants to remove "white space," which includes characters other than a simple space.

Comment: @HeyItsProdigy I updated my answer to use your variable names and `mkdir()` code.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$dir = 'this is a example';
$dir = trim(str_replace(' ','',$dir));
mkdir($dir, 0777);
```